# a linux cli equivalent to mac's "open" command? or windows "start" command?

Tags: linux, command-line

In a mac cli, I can type `open file.jpg` and the mac will automatically figure out the correct application and open it for me.

In Windows, the `start` command does the same thing, but also will open up explorer to working directory if given no parameters.

Is there a way to do that in linux? (maybe only certain distros?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If [XdgUtils](http://portland.freedesktop.org/wiki/) is installed files can be opened via

```
xdg-open file
```

Otherwise there might be something provided by the desktop environment, e.g. for gnome

```
gnome-open file
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `xdg-open`.  Should be supported by most distros and desktops.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can append an ampersand to your line:

Windows :

```
start "Title" /MIN <application>
```

Linux :

```
<application> &
```

As a result, you'll see the process ID of the application and in the terminal window where you're located, you'll see the output of the application.

Comment: This suggestion will start a program running in the background. I was interested in taking any _file_ (not just executables) and having the OS automatically find the default program associated with that file, and then have that program start it for me. For example, in Windows I can type `start file.jpg` and it will find the image viewer program and open the file for me.